# How does one expression factor into the other?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does $$(k+1)(k^2+2k)(3k+5)$$ factor into $$(k)(k^2-1)(3k+2) + 12k(k+1)^2$$

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you ask how to get to this result, or how it is possible to have several different factorisation, or if the two factorisation are really equal?

Comment: Is the second expression really factored?

Comment: How are these two factorizations equal @Martigan? I cannot see how I get from the LHS to the RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both terms are equal to $(3k + 5)(k + 2)(k + 1)k$, because 
$$
k(k^2-1)(3k+2)+12k(k+1)^2= k(3k^3 + 14k^2 + 21k + 10)=(3k + 5)(k + 2)(k + 1)k.
$$

Comment: How does $(3k+10)(k+1)$ factor into $(3k+5)(k+2)$?

Comment: It does not ! Take $k=-1$, then the LHS is zero, but the RHS is nonzero.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for that.

Comment: How do I factor $3k^2 + 11k + 10$?!

Comment: Since $k=-2$ is a root of $3k^2+11k+10$ you do polynomial division $(3k^2+11k+10)$ by $(k+2)$, which gives you $3k+5$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $RHS=k(k^2-1)(3k+2) + 12k(k+1)^2 = k(k+1)((k-1)(3k+2)+12(k+1))=k(k+1)(3k^2+2k-3k-2+12k+12)=k(k+1)(3k^2+11k+10)=k(k+1)(k+2)(3k+5)=LHS$